C++ using a class name and a "normal" variable as a constructor parameter simultaneously
Dear Experts my concept is the following: I have some structured data (in struct F_data), and I want to fit various function on this data (eg. parabola, hyperbola etc.). Therefore I have a base class (class F_function) and child classes (eg. class parabola). The fit is done by an other class (due to other reasons) fit, whose constructor has two parameters: the fiting function and the fiting data. Here is my code:
#include <iostream>

struct F_data{
    /*...*/
};

class F_function{
    
    public: virtual int N_fparams() = 0;
    public: virtual double eval(double x, double* &fparams) = 0;
    
    public: F_function(){};
    public: virtual ~F_function(){};
};

class parabola: public F_function{
    public: int N_fparams(){return 3;}
    public: double eval(double x, double* &fparams){
        return fparams[0]*pow(x,2)+fparams[1]*x+fparams[2];
    }
};

class hyperbola: public F_fuction{/*...*/};

class fit{
    /*...*/
    public: fit(F_function& fugg, const F_data& data){/*...*/};
/*...*/
};

int main(){
    
    F_data diana;
    /* Loading data to diana*/
   /* ... */
   
    parabola petra;
    
     fit apple(petra,diana);             // Works
     fit banana(parabola,F_data diana);   // "Works", but diana is empty of course
     fit citrone(parabola,diana);          // Does not work: ' error: ‘diana’ is not a type '
    
return 0;
}

The code works if I create a named child object, and call the constructor of the fiting class with her (see fit apple(petra,diana)). That is good and should be enough :)
However, I am curious: since the fitting class only describes how to evaluate the fiting function (public: double eval(...)), I do not need to create an object ('petra') I only should need the name of the child class ('parabola'), like I have tried with fit citrone(parabola,diana). Is there a way to achieve this?

"Therefore I have a base class ..." why inheritance? You only need a free function data fit(data), i suppose thats also the answer to your quesiton

Have a look at template functions and parameter packs

Yes, just create a temporary object, fit citrone(parabola(),diana);. The code parabola() invokes the default constructor to create a parabola object. Since this object is unnamed it's known as a tempoarary.

double* &fparam is a very fragile "C" style interface. Use const std::vector<double>&, or std::span<double> or in your case since you seem to expect 3 doubles. Make it either a struct or const std::array<double,3>&

Presuming every eval() shares same signature. Strategy pattern fits better than inheritance. That is fitStrategy['parabola'].fit() where fitStrategy could be a std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function>.

Use a inline constexpr tag object. I.e., std::in_place.

You could remove all the virtual functions without damaging your example code. class F_function {/*...*/}; would imply that unneeded members have been omitted, and once it's used as a base class, class parabola: public F_function{ /*...*/};, it would be reasonable to guess that among the unneeded members is at least one virtual function.

"// "Works", but diana is empty of course" -- The accuracy of this claim depends on what you mean by "works" (and by "empty"). I can accept that it compiles. However, suggesting that you have defined a variable named banana (or that this diana defines an object) is another story...

fit banana(parabola,F_data diana);   // "Works", but diana is empty of course.   This "works" in the sense that it does not have a diagnosable error.   This line, however, does not define an object of type fit named banana, and certainly does not call any constructor of fit.   It is declaring a function named banana(), which accepts two arguments (one of type parabola and one of type F_data) and returns a fit by value (the token diana can be omitted, or replaced with Unfit, and the code will still compile in the same manner).

fit apple(petra,diana); defines a local variable, and initialises it with lvalue references to other local variables.
fit banana(parabola,F_data diana); declares a function. It has an unnamed parabola parameter and an F_data parameter named diana at this declaration.
fit citrone(parabola,diana); is neither a local variable nor a function, because you are mixing types and values.
You need a parabola object that lives at least as long as fit references it, so fit citrone(parabola(),diana); also doesn't work, because the temporary parabola object will cease to exist at the ;, and you will have a dangling reference.
